# What's the relationship between openGauss and PG?

Tags: open-gauss

What is the relationship between the openGauss and PG? Is there any limitation for user?

Answer (score 1):

Huawei open-sourced the OpenGauss database on June 30 last year. The openGauss database kernel is evolved based on postgresql 9.2.4.

https://cloud.tencent.com/developer/article/1674346

Answer (score 0):

The openGaussian kernel originates from PostgreSQL9.2 and PG XC, incubated from the Huawei Gaussian DB commercial database, and is an open-source database with enterprise level capabilities. The total code line for OpenGauss is about 120w, including 95w lines for the kernel, 70w lines for modifications and additions in the kernel, and about 25w lines for PG interfaces and public functions, which means about 74% are self-developed. OpenGauss has made in-depth modifications in architecture, transactions, storage engine, optimizer, and Kunpeng chip optimization

There is no direct connection between the two databases in terms of usage, and users can use them as two independent databases